# Expand TreeItem in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I wish that it would turn around TreeItem when you click on it and not on the "+".
I added the following code:

```
Tree.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<TreeItem>() {

        @Override
        public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<TreeItem> event) {
            event.getSelectedItem().setState(!event.getSelectedItem().getState());
        }
    });
```

TreeItem expand but not collapsed, because onSelection activated twice.
What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue in GWT issue tracker:

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=3660&q=Tree%20selection&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars